# Show each table after the other in UNION SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to show two result sets in one result set, using `UNION`

The problem is, I want it to show all of the first table's records, and **then** go to the next one

But since SQL Server automatically orders the results by the first column, the final results get ordered by `ID` column, which both tables have

Both tables have a column with the `ID` of 1, 2, 3 and so on, and therefore the result of the `UNION` is like this:

```
[table 1].[record 1]
[table 2].[record 1]
[table 1].[record 2]
[table 2].[record 2]
```

I want it to show like this:

```
[table 1].[record 1]
[table 1].[record 2]
[table 1].[record 3]
[table 2].[record 1]
[table 2].[record 2]
[table 2].[record 3]
```

Comment: "since SQL Server automatically orders the results by the first column" no it doesn't (there is no guarantee on order), unless you add an `ORDER BY`. What is probably happening is that you had `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, in which case it needs to de-duplicate the data, so it sorts it to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an "ordering column" e.g.

```
select 0 Orderb, T1.*
from Table1 T1

union all

select 1 Orderb, T2.*
from Table2 T2

order by OrderBy, id; -- whatever columns you wish to order by
```

Comment: Note that ordering by `OrderBy` only means that no sort is physically done, just a `Merge Concatenation`

Comment: Tnx Dale

And also, is there a way to Hide this column?

I didn't find anything that could help with hiding columns in the output of a query

Comment: @Mohammad just use a sub-query.

Comment: @Charlieface yes, but that's actually the point

I don't want there to be any ordering between records from two different tables. only within each table's records (which is done by default on the first column of each table)

Comment: @DaleK Tnx a lot <3. so just to be clear, there is no way to `Hide` one column, right?

Comment: @DaleK What you suggested would look like this => `select Name, OfficeID, Salary from (the query in the answer above)` but the i get this error that says, order by isn't allowed in views, ..., subqueries ..., and the subquery here (being the query you wrote in the answer) has an `order by` clause in it, so what should i do?

Comment: @Mohammad you order by **outside** the sub-query

Comment: @DaleK I don't know why, but I can't run the query. this is my actuall query `select * from (select  0 ResultOrder, e.* from Employees e union all select 1 ResultOrder,ee.* from employee2 ee)`i just get the error => incorrect syntax near ')' (meaning the last parentheses). what's wrong here?

Comment: You need to alias your sub-query.

Comment: @Mohammad `select Name, OfficeID, Salary from (select  0 ResultOrder, e.* from Employees e union all select 1 ResultOrder,ee.* from employee2 ee) AS unioned order by ResultOrder`

Comment: @Charlieface Can I ask, why do we have to allies our subquery?

Comment: That's just how it is, all derived tables (subqueries) used in a `FROM` need aliases

Comment: @Mohammad you need a way to identify every table/derived table. Image you joined your sub-query into another table, and both your sub-query and the other table had a column named "id" - you need some way to identify which is which.